# Obtener nombres de columnas en Mysql atraves de python

Tags: mysql, python

Tengo este codigo

```
import mysql.connector as cn

base_datos = "base_datos"
dbConnect = {"host":"localhost", "user":"root", "password":"***********", "database":base_datos}
conn = cn.connect(**dbConnect)

cursor = conn.cursor()
```

y quisiera obtener los nombres de columnas de una tabla de prueba que hice

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Como debería hacerlo?

Comment: en sql es `SHOW COLUMNS FROM prueba`

Answer (score 3):

Prueba con `pymysql`:

```
import pymysql
con = pymysql.connect('localhost','root','','provincias')
conn = con.cursor(pymysql.cursors.DictCursor)
conn.execute("SELECT * FROM provincias;")
provincias=conn.fetchall()
print(provincias)
```

Obtendrás un diccionario con toda la tabla. Si quieres obtener el nombre de los campos, únicamente tienes que recorrer el primer elemento con un `for`:

```
for c in provincias[0]:
    print(c)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import mysql.connector as cn

base_datos = "base_datos"

dbConnect = {"host":"localhost", "user":"root", "password":"***********","database":base_datos}

conn = cn.connect(**dbConnect)

cursor = conn.cursor()

columnas = cursor.column_names

print(columnas)
```